# Parse different JSON data on same activity while clicking different buttons

Tags: android, json

I want to Parse different JSON data by using same activity, on clicking different buttons. I just want to conclude that, I have several ImageViews on an activity and when I click in any ImageView, it must open same activity but the data should be different according to clicking of ImageViews. Here, I have my java class of activity where different ImageViews are present.

```
    imageView1 = findViewById(R.id.Hospital1);
    imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, DetailActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.Hospital2);
    imageView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, DetailActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    imageView3 = findViewById(R.id.Hospital3);
    imageView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, DetailActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    imageView4 = findViewById(R.id.Hospital4);
    imageView4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, DetailActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

And this is my DetailActivity which I want to call on clicking any of these ImageViews.

```
    aQuery.progress(R.id.progressBar).ajax(fetchurl, JSONArray.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void callback(String url, JSONArray array, AjaxStatus status) {
            super.callback(url, array, status);
            Log.i("response", url + "response:" + array);

            ArrayList<UserInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                try {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    UserInfo info = new UserInfo();
                    info.id = object.getString("Id");
                    info.servicename = object.getString("name");
                    info.amount = object.getString("amount");
                    list.add(info);

                    textView1.append(info.id + "." + "\n\n");
                    textView2.append(info.servicename + " " + "\n\n");
                    textView3.append(info.amount + " " + "\n\n");

                    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                } catch (JSONException je) {
                    Toast.makeText(aQuery.getContext(), "Error Parsing Data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(aQuery.getContext(), "Something went wrong...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
            if (status.getCode() == 500) {
                Toast.makeText(aQuery.getContext(), "Server is busy, Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (status.getCode() == 404) {
                Toast.makeText(aQuery.getContext(), "Resource Not Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (status.getCode() == 200) {

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(aQuery.getContext(), "Unexpected Error Occured !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

My problem is when I click on any ImageView it opens the DetailActivity but all the data is same for all ImageViews. Is there something I could also do with database? Here is an image of my database [Click here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJaKq.png)

I am new in android programming, it would be more thankful if I got the block of code where I have to edit my code. I just want to show data of "*name2*" and "*amount2*" database column for imageView2.

Currently I am using *String fetchurl = "http://192.168.0.111/MyApplication/select.php";* url. You can further view my Json data.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the `fetchUrl` that will be going to use by the `DetailActivity`:

```
imageView1 = findViewById(R.id.Hospital1);
imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, DetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("fetch_url", "http://baseurl.com/imageview1");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
//....repeat this code with the other imageView, imageView2, imageView3....
```

And you can fetch it on your `DetailActivity` using:

```
String fetchUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("fetch_url", ""); //2nd param is default value

aQuery.progress(R.id.progressBar).ajax(fetchUrl, JSONArray.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONArray>() {
.....
```

Now you can use the specific `url` base on a specific click on your `imageView`

Comment: Sir, I am new in android programming, so i am confused that what i have to insert inside intent.putExtra(). I have put name2 and amount2 for another ImageView in database. Could you please edit and send me the code where I have to edit and put some changes. It will be more thankful if you also show me to change over in my DetailActivity. I will be waiting for your answer sir.

Comment: I've updated my answer, and I saw that you're using fetchUrl variable, you can specify the fetchUrl from the onClick of each imageView to specify the data for that click.

Comment: Sir again I have updated my question with my database image. Sir i want to fetch my data from same url; I don't have different url for different imageviews.

Comment: For that, it means you also need to update your php code that can catch a GET parameter, so you can create a conditional statement to fetch the specific column base on the parameter passed.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir! Your code works when I send only (fetch_url) inside getStringExtra... And I checked it by building different url for different image and it completely works by sending different data on different image on same Activity. You rock it !! Thank you again!!

Comment: You can mark it as an answer so others can make a reference of it. Your welcome.

Answer (score 0):

change fetchurl at click of imageview

Answer (score 0):

All data is same because there is no image specific value passed to your Detail Activity. How do you identify which image was clicked?

Implementing onClickListener for Your activity could be optimal in your case...

```
public class YourActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

inside OnCreate(){....
map your imageviews to clicklisteners,
 imageView4.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()){

        case R.id.hosptial1:

            Intent intent = new Intent(..., DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", ..button);
            intent.putExtra("key", ..value);
            startActivity(intent);

            break;


        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Intents are one of the ways for passing data between activities. Assuming `fetchurl` needs image specific value in request, once you get the same in DetailActivity, it can be used in the request.